# Flex video stream recording (not from webcam)

Tags: apache-flex, video, recording

I am developing a web based media player. On server side, i am using red5's OflaDemo to stream videos, on client side (flex 4), a VideoPlayer control plays the incoming streamed video.

I want the client application to make / record clips from the played video and save them on the server. 
I have some idea of netstreams and know netstream.publish is used to save recorded video on the server. 
All the examples i find are of recording from webcam, i haven't found a way to set the streamed video as the source / input for the netstream to publish.

Help in this regard is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: As per my understanding you are making video from other recorded video? Like video cutter used to cut video from other video?

Comment: You can say that. I want to give users the ability to cut and save clips from video being streamed from my red5 server and publish those clips on red5.